# Terraform map in module pass to resource for_each

Tags: terraform

I would like to pass map variables from module to resource to run `for_each` like this. How can I do that? In my case the module doesn't get variables.
Terraform v1.5.5

```
module "vultr" {
  source = "./modules"
  vultr_api     = "KLQ"
  firewall_name = "External HTTP, SSH"
  vpc_name      = "A beautiful name of my VPC"
  region        = var.region_frankfurt_de
  instance = {
    "application" = {
      instance_hostname = "app-server"
      instance_label    = "app-server-label"
      instance_tags     = ["go", "app"]
      ssh_key_name      = ["key"]
      plan              = var.plan_5_usd_vc2-1c-1gb
      os_id             = var.os_id_ubuntu_20_04_lts
      label             = "label"
      enable_ipv6       = false
      backups           = "enabled"
      backups_schedule  = "monthly"
      backups_dow       = 7
      backups_hour      = 1
      ddos_protection   = false
      activation_email  = false
    },
    "database" = {
      instance_hostname = "db-server"
      instance_label    = "db-server-label"
      instance_tags     = ["go", "db"]
      ssh_key_name      = ["key"]
      plan              = var.plan_5_usd_vc2-1c-1gb
      os_id             = var.os_id_ubuntu_20_04_lts
      label             = "label"
      enable_ipv6       = false
      backups           = "enabled"
      backups_schedule  = "monthly"
      backups_dow       = 7
      backups_hour      = 1
      ddos_protection   = false
      activation_email  = false
    }
  }
}
```

./module

```
resource "vultr_instance" "my_instance" {
  for_each          = var.instance
  plan              = each.value.plan
  region            = each.value.region
  os_id             = each.value.os_id
  label             = each.value.label
  tags              = each.value.instance_tags
  hostname          = each.value.instance_hostname
  firewall_group_id = vultr_firewall_group.firewallgroups.id
  vpc_ids           = [vultr_vpc.vpc.id]
  ssh_key_ids       = [data.vultr_ssh_key.ssh_key.id]
  enable_ipv6       = each.value.enable_ipv6
  ddos_protection   = each.value.ddos_protection
  activation_email  = each.value.activation_email
  backups           = each.value.backups
  backups_schedule {
    type = try(each.value.backups_schedule, null)
    dow  = try(each.value.backups_dow, null)
    hour = try(each.value.backups_hour, null)
  }
}
```

Comment: What does that mean? Are there any errors? If so, add them to the question. Also, is the variable `instances` defined in the module?

Answer (score 0):

I used this way. Now I can add number of servers in locals variables and get desired number of different sizes of servers.

```
locals {
  instance = {
    "application" = {
      instance_hostname = "app-server"
      instance_label    = "app-server-label"
      instance_tags     = ["go", "app"]
      ssh_key_name      = ["key"]
      plan              = var.plan_5_usd_vc2-1c-1gb
      os_id             = var.os_id_ubuntu_20_04_lts
      label             = "label"
      enable_ipv6       = false
      backups           = "enabled"
      backups_schedule  = "monthly"
      backups_dow       = 7
      backups_hour      = 1
      ddos_protection   = false
      activation_email  = false
    },
    "database" = {
      instance_hostname = "db-server"
      instance_label    = "db-server-label"
      instance_tags     = ["go", "db"]
      ssh_key_name      = ["key"]
      plan              = var.plan_5_usd_vc2-1c-1gb
      os_id             = var.os_id_ubuntu_20_04_lts
      label             = "label"
      enable_ipv6       = false
      backups           = "enabled"
      backups_schedule  = "monthly"
      backups_dow       = 7
      backups_hour      = 1
      ddos_protection   = false
      activation_email  = false
    }
  }
}

module "vultr" {
  source           = "./modules"
  for_each         = local.instance
  firewall_name    = "External HTTP, SSH"
  vpc_name         = "A beautiful name of my VPC"
  region           = var.region_frankfurt_de
  hostname         = each.value.instance_hostname
  instance_label   = each.value.instance_label
  tags             = each.value.instance_tags
  ssh_key_name     = each.value.ssh_key_name
  plan             = each.value.plan
  os_id            = each.value.os_id
  label            = each.value.label
  enable_ipv6      = each.value.enable_ipv6
  backups          = each.value.backups
  backups_schedule = each.value.backups_schedule
  backups_dow      = each.value.backups_dow
  backups_hour     = each.value.backups_hour
  ddos_protection  = each.value.ddos_protection
  activation_email = each.value.activation_email
}
```

Module

```
data "vultr_ssh_key" "ssh_key" {
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = var.ssh_key_name
  }
}

resource "vultr_instance" "my_instance" {
  plan              = var.plan
  region            = var.region
  os_id             = var.os_id
  label             = var.label
  tags              = var.tags
  hostname          = var.hostname
  firewall_group_id = vultr_firewall_group.firewallgroups.id
  vpc_ids           = [vultr_vpc.vpc.id]
  ssh_key_ids       = [data.vultr_ssh_key.ssh_key.id]
  enable_ipv6       = var.enable_ipv6
  ddos_protection   = var.ddos_protection
  activation_email  = var.activation_email
  user_data         = file("./modules/cloud-config.yaml")
  backups           = var.backups
  backups_schedule {
    type = var.backups_schedule
  }
}
```